# How can i plot graph of random array having with 20 minutes time and 8 ms interval?

Tags: python, arrays, random, plot, graphics

I have a problem with ploting graph in python. I need to create a random array and time array. Then i will plot a graph with them.
Time array should start with 0 and it should finish with 20 minutes. The interval of time array should be 8 milliseconds.

I tried to write a code like this: (But the graphic doesnt seems good. Could anyone help me please?)

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

random_array = np.random.rand(150000)
time_array = np.linspace(0, 1200, 150000)

# The number 1200 is the conversion of 20 minutes to seconds. 
# And the number 150000 is for interval. (1200 second / 0.008 second )

plt.plot(time_array, random_array)

plt.xlabel('Time (second)')
plt.ylabel('Value')
```

Comment: what do you mean "graphic doesnt seems good"?  what are you getting, what are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

I made a few changes to your code, and uploaded the plot.

(1) changed the plt.plot to plt.scatter

(2) moved your comments to the top, and used comment syntax of # instead of "

(3) added np.sort() to the y-variable data, just to make it easier to see in this example.

- For your actual dataset, don't use the np.sort() because in your dataset the time variable (x-axis) is probably aligned with your independent variable (y-axis) … sorting it would mess up the data.
- Without the np.sort() in the example, it just shows a block of random scatter dots.

```py
# (The number 1200 is the conversion of 20 minutes to seconds. 
# And the number 150000 is for interval. (1200 second / 0.008 second ))
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
random_array= np.random.rand(150000)
time_array= np.linspace(0,1200,150000) 
plt.scatter(time_array,np.sort(random_array))
plt.xlabel('Time (second)')
plt.ylabel('Value')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your helping. If i would show in a histogram can i write the code like this:  "plt.hist(random_array,bins=150)"

Comment: I think that's right.  I have used seaborn in the past, which is like a wrapper on top of matplotlib, but cleaner interface.  http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html  https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html

Comment: One way that I worked on my python visualization skills, was to look at the Kaggle User Rankings, and look for "Kernel Grandmasters" (not "Competition Grandmasters") and learn from their code.  For example, here is an excellent example from username "SRK" currently #3 on Kernels grandmasters (https://www.kaggle.com/sudalairajkumar/simple-exploration-notebook-zillow-prize) … just go through his examples one-by-one and apply to your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can tell your code is fine, I'd just try and express your constraints directly in the code, e.g:

```
import numpy as np

time_seconds = np.arange(0, 20 * 60, 0.008)
random_values = np.random.rand(*time_seconds.shape)
```

i.e. just calculate `20 * 60` seconds and use `0.008` directly, putting the units somewhere obvious in the variable name.  Python can work out that this would be 150k samples for us (it's a computer!) and we just reuse this value to sample some random values

Comment: Thanks for your helping. If i would show in a histogram can i write the code like this:  "plt.hist(random_array,bins=150)"

Comment: yes, but given you know it's uniform it's not going to be very interesting!  i.e. bins will be Poisson distributed with mean=1000.